# How bad practice it is to test a site using `Execute Javascript` when I don't have sufficient knowledge of robot-selenium's built in functions?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework and Selenium2Library and it is frustrating that I am not able to test certain things and have to spend hours of searching the web for a mere hint of how things work..

But then,... I found the magic `Execute Javascript`. I am pretty skilled with javascript, so I thought that I could just test it with it and `return` a `true/false/error message/whatever` which I would then just check using built in comparative functions.

Is that legit? How mad am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execute javascript function is great to do very specific things that are not covered by the Selnium framework. However, Selenium is a great framework providing lot of services. Using Javascript only will drive you crazy as you will have difficulties to maintain your code. A simple line in Java (or Python, RUby, C#, ...) using the selenium API might requires a lot more line in javascript.

There is a quick start guide on Selenium at http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/ .

If you need assistance on a specific topic (how to ...), feel free to create another question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask yourself what your goals are. If the main goal is to catch or prevent defects, and you are working on a small, single-person project, just about anything that gets you closer to that goal is OK.

**However**, if your goal also includes creating a test suite that is easy to read and easy to maintain over time, you should think about learning how to use the keywords to their best advantage, and use javascript only when it is the only option.

If you use javascript to avoid learning the selenium keywords it may help you in the short term, but it will hurt you in the long term. For many people, the best way to learn is by doing. It can be painful at first, but the knowledge you gain will pay off over time.

There's a saying related to when you are interviewing someone for a job and they claim they have ten years experience doing something. As an interviewer, I try to determine if they really have ten years of experience, or one year of experience repeated ten times. If you stick to what you know, you end up with one year repeated ten times.